# GCC: Executing Code at "Preinitialization" time

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, glibc

So on Linux when a C++ program that was compiled/linked with gcc, has its executable loaded the following happens:

1. exec* syscall
2. LD dynamic libraries loaded
3. C++ static initialization
4. entry point of main

Suppose I have some function with prototype `void f()`,

Is there some way (via source modification, attributes, compiler/linker options, etc) to link the executable with f such that it will be executed between step 1 and 2 ?

What about between step 2 and 3 ?

(Clearly there is no standard way to do this, I am asking for a platform-specifc, compiler-specific way for a recent versions of gcc/linux/x86_64/glibc/binutils)

Comment: Between step 1 and 2? So you want to run some code before the image is ready to run?

Comment: Very unlikely. Also what do you need that for?

Comment: When dynamic libraries are loaded, isn't there some mechanism by which they can execute some code?  I want to execute f before this.

Comment: `void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_init(void);` ( from http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html)

Comment: yes exactly, so these library constructors would be executed during "step 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could do this between (1) and (2), or between (2) and (3). Step 2 "ld dynamic libraries loaded" is actually done by calling the dynamic linker, `ld.so`. Typically, this would be `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or similar; its part of glibc. However, the path is actually specified in the executable, so you can use any path you want.

```
$ readelf -l `which bash`
⋮
Program Headers:
⋮
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]

⋮
```

This is in addition to doing things like `LD_PRELOAD`/`LD_AUDIT`.

For between (2) and (3), it sounds like you just want to change the entrypoint address.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for the application.  If the poster could modify the executable, why would he have the requirement to run things before it's linked at runtime?  Just link against the right libraries in the first place.

Comment: @AndyRoss OP specifically said "via source modification, attributes, compiler/linker options, etc" so I think changing the ELF interpreter field is OK. No clue what OP is up to; I hope the answer is "heavy wizardry" else OP is of questionable sanity :-P

Answer (score -1):

Basically no.  The `execve()` system call will wipe the environment.  There is no way for anything you do in your address space to survive into the new one.  You are allowed to send file descriptors (except ones flagged CLOEXEC, of course) into the new process, and you can pass it arguments via the environment.

... which gives you something that might do what you want.  You can set LD_PRELOAD to load a shared library "first", before any code is run from your target executable and before any symbols are resolved by the shared linker.  It's not clear from your question whether this meets your requirements or not.